# Node JS - Express.js get query with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm quite new to JavaScript and Node JS and I have a such a situation. When I try to call `get` of `express.js` with a single parameter everything works fine, but when I try to call `get` with more than one parameter, it trims the query.
For example I have such call and function

```
app.get('path/data', myFunc);
// in another file
function myFunc(req, res) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

When the url is `path/data?id=5` or `path/data?name=foo` everything is fine. But when I use for example url like `path/data?id=5&name=foo` in myFunc I get url as `path/data?id=5`. So I get url's first part - what is before `&` sign.

Now what am I doing wrong? Is there something that I'm missing? How can I get whole url in `myFunc` without being trimmed?

Comment: Did you use `req.query`? You're most likely using `req.params`.

Comment: I tested your program with `req.query` it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm logging `req.query` and it shows `{ "id": "5" }` and nothing about `name`.

Comment: Then it's not the same routing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I was requesting via `curl` and it turns out that shell command trims in case of there is an `&` in the url. So there is a need no add quotes like this

```
curl "path/data?id=5&name=foo"
```

Comment: Correct.  Tried in browser, no issues.  Also the specification says you are correct.  http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100099/why-is-curl-truncating-this-query-string

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
app.get('path/data?:id?:name')
```

And for retrieving the values, use `req.query.id` and `req.query.name`.

For accessing the REST api, you need to hit: 
http://localhost:8080/demo?id=3&name=stack

So, by this you can add multiple parameters in your api.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It makes no difference to use those question marks, they neither filter or reject a bogus header.  The problem really is with curl.  Try browser vs. curl.

Comment: This solution works well in browser. with no issues.