# How to configure nginx to read multiple url parameters?

Tags: http, url, nginx, parameters, nginx-location

I have a running nginx server with the following `location` config:

```
    location /test_args/ {
        return 200 $arg_z$arg_x$arg_y;
    }
```

So I'm trying to send `z`, `x` and `y` values in response.

When running http request

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8090/test_args/?z=12&x=34&y=56
```

I get only `12` in response. This is a value of the first parameter `z`. Other parameters are omitted.
I expect the response to be `123456`

How do I make nginx read multiple URL parameters?

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Do you have any rewrites or something before which replaces the url? Try returning `$request_uri` to see the current url.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R `$request_uri` returns everything before first `&` sign. Here's the output: `/test_args/?z=12`

Comment: I doubt it is because some other script is rewriting you request uri and striping off the params

Comment: Tried to quote url in CURL and it worked eventually. Strange

Comment: It is because the shell is interpreting the `&` differently. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10691154/3150943