# How to count MailChimp list members with status "pending" via MailChimp API 3?

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

It could return the emails associated with "status": "pending" or just the number of accounts with status pending for that list. I'm just interested in knowing how many signups fall off as a result of the double opt in process.

I was able to test in the MailChimp API playground for a limited number of members, but not sure how to do the request for the full list. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know how many members with pending status in a certain list, then you can do so by making a GET request to the following endpoint as described [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#read-get_lists_list_id_members):

```
/lists/{list_id}/members
```

Change `{list_id}` to the id of your list and set the `status` query string parameter to `pending`. You will get a response containing `total_items` field and the value is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much - the issue is resolved! Originally it was just returning 10 results but then I read that with the latest API you have to pass in count and offset parameters to get more results beyond 10. Anyway this is what I ran `curl -H "Authorization: apikey myAPIKeyHere" https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/myListIDHere/members‌​?status=pending` then whatever parameters for the section of the list I wanted.

Comment: Yes you're right. You should utilize the `count` and `offset` parameters if you want to get all of the pending emails. That also depends on how many total records indicated by the `total_items` in the response body.

Comment: I celebrated too soon  `total_items` is not working for the count... perhaps I am not requesting it properly. If you know offhand the proper way with curl I'd really appreciate it, but if not no worries you've already been a huge help.

Comment: Your original request: `curl -H "Authorization: apikey myAPIKeyHere" https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/myListIDHere/members‌​‌​?status=pending` is fine. You'll get 10 results, but you'll also get `total_items` in the response body, and that's what you need for making the second request in order to get all of the pending emails. For example if the `total_items` says 100, then you should make the same request again, but with `count` parameter set to 100. The response will contain 100 results and you can enumerate through the `members` field in the response body.

Comment: For some reason when I run `curl -H "Authorization: apikey myAPIKeyHere" https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/myListIDHere/members‌​‌​‌​?status=pending` I get the response of total_items and 10 email addresses as expected, but when I add count to the query string with the `total_items` returned in the first query to that original request, I get a response that has 0 total items, and 0 emails in the response. I've tried doing the query a few different ways, but all have come up empty. Anyway appreciate your help so far and no worries if you don't have further ideas but thought I would ask.

Comment: took chatting with mailchimp help but it turns out the shell was truncating the query after the & - so they were only getting the offset, not the count parameter. Adding quotes fixed the issue [more info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100099/why-is-curl-truncating-this-query-string)