# Jenkins Build With Parameters Only Taking First Parameter

Tags: jenkins, terminal, jenkins-plugins, interpretation

I set up a Jenkins build that uses the "Publish over SSH" plugin to remotely execute an ansible script, injecting the variables into the call to `ansible-playbook`

The command that Jenkins will remotely execute:

```
ansible-playbook /home/username/test/test.yml --extra-vars "ui_version=$UI_VERSION web_version=$WEB_VERSION git_release=$GIT_RELEASE release_environment=$RELEASE_ENVIRONMENT"
```

Which is triggered by the following curl:

```
curl -k --user username:secretPassword -v -X POST https://jenkins/job/Ansible_Test/buildWithParameters?UI_VERSION=abc&WEB_VERSION=def&GIT_RELEASE=ghi&RELEASE_ENVIRONMENT=jkl
```

Which should be utilizing the following variables:

[image: jenkins_vars]

**My Problem:** only the first parameter gets injected, as you can see on the longest line of the console output on Jenkins below:

```
...
SSH: EXEC: completed after 201 ms
SSH: Opening exec channel ...
SSH: EXEC: channel open
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [ansible-playbook /home/dholt2/test/test.yml --extra-vars "ui_version=abc web_version= git_release= release_environment="] ...
SSH: EXEC: connected
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the terminal was trying to interpret the `&` after the first parameter, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100099/why-is-curl-truncating-this-query-string). Quoting the URL resulted in a successful transmission and variable injection.

I should've known it was the cause when the command waited for more input.