# Error: Unable to do CURL get request using string condition

Tags: windows, postgresql, curl, cmd, get

Yes, I can see a lot of relevant [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100099/why-is-curl-truncating-this-query-string) at SOV, I already tried a few suggested solutions but they didn't work out for me. I am trying to do GET request to a remote PostgreSQL database (within the network). I am on Windows 10 (x64) and using CURL CMD tool.

I am trying to retrieve data from the remote PostgreSQL database using `where` clause that finds the exact street name and house number (both in `text` format). Here is my query:

```
curl "http://my_host:my_port/my_table?select=id,lat,long&street_name=\"Reading\"&house_num=\"14\"
```

and I get the following error:

```
{"details":"unexpected \"\\\"\" expecting \"not\" or operator (eq, gt, ...)","message":"\"failed to parse filter (\"Reading\")\" (line 1, column 1)"}
```

Can someone help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like, that there is a missing " at the end of the command?

Comment: @SimonSchiff: Just tried by putting `"` at the end and still the same error.

Comment: Maybe use `""` instead of `\"` for inner double quotes? Something like `curl "http://my_host:my_port/my_table?select=id,lat,long&street_name=""Reading""&house_num=""14"""`.

Comment: It is not possible to escape `"` with ``\`` in an argument string interpreted by Windows command processor `cmd.exe`. There is no possibility to get `"` interpreted as literal character by `cmd.exe` inside an argument string to pass to an application like `curl.exe`. However, this is not really needed as the url with `"` inside can be percent encoded. The character `"` should be [percent encoded](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-encoded-bytes) in the url to have a working url. A percent sign must be escaped with one more `%` in a Windows batch file to be interpreted as literal character.

Comment: I suggest to use: `curl.exe "http://my_host:my_port/my_table?select=id,lat,long&street_name=%%22Reading%%22&house_num=%%2214%%22"`

Comment: @JosefZ: I tried with `""` also and same the error :(.

Comment: @Mofi: I also tried your suggestion and the error persists! I am not using a batch file, I am usnig Windows CMD.

Comment: On Windows command line try: `curl.exe "http://my_host:my_port/my_table?select=id,lat,long&street_name=%22Reading%22&house_num=%2214%22"` Perhaps your host accepts also an url with `'` instead of `"`. So try also: `curl.exe "http://my_host:my_port/my_table?select=id,lat,long&street_name='Reading'&house_num='14'"`

Comment: @Mofi: Tried both and got erros : `...."message":"\"failed to parse filter (\"Reading\")\" (line 1, column 1)"}` and `....."message":"\"failed to parse filter ('Reading')\" (line 1, column 1)"}`.

Comment: And when you omit the quotes inside the url and use just `curl.exe "http://my_host:my_port/my_table?select=id,lat,long&street_name=Reading&house_num=14"` which is usually the standard for url queries?

Comment: @Mofi: Unfortunately, the same error: `"message":"\"failed to parse filter (Reading)\" (line 1, column 1)"}`.

Comment: Then there is no other chance to pass the url if valid at all with `"` using environment variables and delayed expansion to `curl.exe` by using a batch file. The command lines for batch file are: 1. `@echo off`, 2. `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion`, 3. `set "MainUrl=http://my_host:my_port/my_table?select=id,lat,long"`, 4. `set "StreetOption=&street_name="`, 5. `set "StreetName="Reading""`, 6. `set "HouseOption=&house_num"`, 7. `set "HouseNumber="14""`, 8. `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, 9. `curl.exe "!MainUrl!!StreetOption!!StreetName!!HouseOption!!HouseNumber!"`

Comment: And the last two lines of the batch file contain both the command `endlocal`. If that does still not work, then `curl.exe` does not like the url or the host does not like the url `http://my_host:my_port/my_table?select=id,lat,long&street_name="Reading"&house_num="14"` and I have no further idea.

Comment: @Mofi: Care to post your batch file code suggestion as an alternate solution/answer? I could try for sure.